# Which one should I use? "OF IT" or "OF WHICH"

Tags: adjectives, clauses

I bought a watermelon from the market, half ---- was rotten, so I threw it away and bought a new one.

It seems to me both of them are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Technically***, if you use *of it*, you have a run-on sentence: both *"I bought a watermelon from the market"* and *"half of it was rotten"* are complete sentences, so you are joining two sentences with a comma splice, which gives a run-on sentence.

On the other hand, *half of which* is really quite formal English, and for everyday writing, most people don't worry too much about run-on sentences (and you can't hear the difference between a comma and a semicolon, so in speech it's not even a run-on sentence). So for most occasions, *of it* might actually be better.

Comment: . . . so long as, if using *it*, it's not punctuated with only a comma. Add *and* after the comma or replace the comma with a semicolon or dash. Or use a period and start a second sentence.